# How to type-hint return type of __getattr__ method?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-typing, getattr

I am curious if there is a way in Python 3 to type hint the return type of `__getattr__()` method in Python.

I have the following dummy code I was using for test purposes:

```py
class MyClass:

    def __getattr__(self, item: str) -> str:
        return 'test'

    def __getattribute__(self, item: str) -> str:
        return 'test'


c = MyClass()

print(c.hello, type(c.hello))  # test <class 'str'>
```

Unfortunately, Pycharm is unable to resolve the type for `hello` attribute from above. I'm not sure but I think it currently is processed as `Any` type.

I also came up with the following variation on the above code, but still unable to get type hinting to work as expected:

```py
from typing import Callable

ReturnsString = Callable[[], str]


class MyClass:

    my_test_fn: ReturnsString = lambda self: 'hello'
    __getattr__: ReturnsString = lambda self, _item: 'test'
    __getattribute__: ReturnsString


c = MyClass()

# type hinting works as expected - return type is `str`
print(c.my_test_fn())

# type hinting doesn't work here still - help?
print(c.hello, type(c.hello))  # test <class 'str'>
```

I am interested to know if anyone knows a workaround where we can type hint the return type of `__getattribute()__` in Python 3.x, perhaps using typing Generics or otherwise.

##### Additional Info

Just to clarify, my use case is that I'm trying to build out a `dict` subclass which supports attribute (dot) access. So I have noticed that type hinting and type-specific suggestions for `__getitem__` works, but not for `__getattr__`. For example:

```py
from typing import Callable

ReturnsString = Callable[[], str]


class MyClass(dict):
    __getattr__: ReturnsString = lambda self, _item: 'test'
    __getattribute__: ReturnsString
    __getitem__: ReturnsString


c = MyClass(hello=123)

# works as expected - return type of c['hello'] is `str`
print(c['hello'], type(c['hello']))  # test <class 'str'>

# type hinting doesn't work here still - help?
print(c.hello, type(c.hello))  # test <class 'str'>
```

Comment: It's probably not going to acknowledge custom attribute handlers, which are often dynamic. Is there any specific use case you're going for with this?

Comment: With the first version of your code, mypy and Pylance both show that `c.hello` is a `str`.  What type checker are you using in Pycharm?

Comment: @Samwise I am actually using built in type checker, but possibly that could be the issue. Do you recommend that I run the code with a type checker or linter? Note that I am just interested in getting type hint and type suggestion list when an attr name is entered.

Comment: mypy is the standard one that I always use for testing, but Pylance somehow installed itself into my VSCode and also seems to work fine.

Comment: [The example works fine in MyPy](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&gist=75ef763699096f3ec7f94dc4bec11d52). Since the point of `__getattr__` and `__getattribute__` is usually heavy meta-programming that is *not* covered by the simple type system of `typing`, there is a good chance every type checker will bail out sooner or later, though.

Comment: @EricJin well, in my specific use case I wanted to create a `dict` subclass with attribute (dot) access. I know with dict you can type hint values like `Dict[int, str]` but was curious if it's possible to do this with attribute access also.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I've updated my example code above. Basically, I am interested in having same type support for `__getitem__` but for `__getattr__`. I hope the use case I've added above makes sense.

Comment: At the very least, your use of `ReturnsString = Callable[[], str]` is wrong – all of these methods take at least one argument in addition to `self`. Either way, even when fixing this at least PyCharm seems to play things safe and assume attributes do not exist until declared.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi you’re entirely right, thanks. will fix the method signature soon. aside from that, do you see any way possible of an approach similar to `Dict[str, int]`, but for attribute instead of key lookup?